# RIA Services Maintaining Inheritance Hierarchy

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, ria

I'm using Silverlight 4, Visual Studio 2010. I have a RIA enabled class library with the following hierarchy:

Entity > SEntity > IncomeEntity > SellableItem

The first 3 are abstract. The client generation class of SellableItem shows it inheriting from Entity. How do I maintain the hierarchy in the client?

Note: I am using NHibernate as my ORM, not EF.